# Google PageSpeed Insights warning about webfont load in spite of font-display:swap

Tags: css, font-face, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, google-fonts

A web page loads a CSS file with multiple `@font-face` rules like

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Open Sans';
font-style: italic;
font-weight: 300;
font-stretch: normal;
src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v26/memQYaGs126MiZpBA-UFUIcVXSCEkx2cmqvXlWq8tWZ0Pw86hd0Rk5hkWV0ewJER.woff2) format('woff2');
unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
font-display: swap;
}
```

As you see, there is the `font-display:swap` declaration, but when I check the page at Google PageSpeed Insights I still receive the warning

> Ensure text remains visible during webfont load

> Leverage the font-display CSS feature to ensure text is user-visible while webfonts
> are loading.

Why?

Comment: Is it solved? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: It disappeared, but I don't remember after what

Comment: I'm puzzled by this as well. Our site uses a single CSS file, and every '@font-face' has an associated 'font-display: swap'. Google PageSpeed Insights will flag some pages, but not others. Can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem across several websites, and believe it or not such a simple "fix" took a long time to discover.

Basically `font-display: swap` will not "fix" this warning from Google.

If you alter your network setting to a Slow 3G you will see visibly how the initial system font is loaded first and only afterwards your own font.

The process of downloading the font into the browser can take several milliseconds and until then your page looks... well banana.

This is ugly and undesired, you want your page to look nice using the font you want **when** you want.

So how to "fix" this? Using **HTTP/2 Preload**. With the Preload directive you can tell the browser to request certain high-priority assets, **which are otherwise discovered late**.

First, you should download the Google Fonts and place it on your web space.

Then, insert the below HTML:

```
<link rel="preload" href="fonts/my-webfont.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
```

In order for this to become effective insert it right below the `<title></title>` HTML tag.

There are many ways to preload assets using HTTP/2, like HTTP Headers. However I recommend the HTML tag "way" because then you can leverage the [early hints](https://blog.cloudflare.com/early-hints/) feature from Cloudflare.

You can of course continue to use **HTTP/2 Push** via Cloudflare or any other CDN that supports it for other assets. **HTTP/2 Preload** only what's necessary, like your fonts, critical CSS, etc.

Do note that [not every browser supports HTTP/2](https://caniuse.com/http2#:%7E:text=HTTP%2F2%20is%20only%20supported,being%20limited%20to%20Windows%2010.) though. Personally, I`m happy supporting only decent and up to date browsers.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks. I added a link with the attributes as you described (however with ttf) and below I inserted inline CSS with @font-face. But when I open the page, I still see "how the initial system font is loaded first and only afterwards" I see my font. The website is connected to Cloudflare with HTTP/2. How can I check that everything is correct and find the problem?

Comment: @stckvrw You can investigate this inside your browser, on the Network tab. The font should be one of the first assets to load. You can see if this was pushed via HTTP/2 with Firefox (Chrome does not show this). Also, there should be a "cf-pushed" header containing the font. However, if all this checks out and you still have the issue, check your page and CSS and see if there are other fonts loading as well. It's really a "manual" approach until you find the cause.

Comment: On the Network tab I see that version is even HTTP/3, but I don't see the cf-pushed header. Is it an option somewhere in Cloudflare settings to be enabled?

Comment: @stckvrw It means HTTP/2 push is not working if you do not see the header. Apologies as I forgot that CF only looks at headers at the moment. Please see: https://blog.cloudflare.com/announcing-support-for-http-2-server-push-2/#fnref1. You need to push via headers when using CF.

Comment: @Mecanik Other fonts, this is an important point. I added font-display and the preload but still got the warning by Pagespeed. Then I realised that the theme declared the same font multiple times across several CSS files, so I had to add font-display everywhere.

Answer (score -2):

It is recommended that you load the font in your HTML head tag. I think that warning is generated because you define the URL in your CSS.

[image]

Comment: No, it doesn't help...